# libgdx shaders- basic shader, but screen is blank

Tags: java, opengl-es, libgdx, shader

I'm trying to understand shaders using libgdx, coming from an XNA/HLSL background.  I'm trying to get a vert/frag shader pair to reproduce the output I get without a shader, but it's not displaying anything.

**Shader creation:**

```
void SetupShader()
{
    ShaderProgram.pedantic = false;
    shader = new ShaderProgram(
            Gdx.files.internal("assets/default.vert").readString(),
            Gdx.files.internal("assets/default.frag").readString());
    if(!shader.isCompiled()) {
        Gdx.app.log("Problem loading shader:", shader.getLog());
    }
    batch.setShader(shader);
}
```

**default.vert:**

```
attribute vec4 a_Position;
attribute vec4 a_Normal;
attribute vec2 a_TexCoord;
attribute vec4 a_Color;

uniform mat4 u_projTrans;

varying vec2 v_texCoords;
varying vec4 v_color;

void main() {
    v_color = a_Color;
    v_texCoords = a_TexCoord;
    gl_Position = u_projTrans * a_Position;
}
```

**default.frag:**

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

varying vec2 v_texCoords;
varying vec4 v_color;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = v_color;
}
```

**Rendering:**

```
batch.begin();
for (GameObject gObj : gameObjects)
    gObj.Draw(batch);
batch.end();
```

Any suggestions here?  I'm new to OpenGL-ES as well, so I may be missing something obvious.  I looked around a bit before posting, and the doc for `SpriteBatch.setShader(ShaderProgram)` was as follows:

> Sets the shader to be used in a GLES 2.0 environment. Vertex position
>   attribute is called "a_position", the texture coordinates attribute is
>   called called "a_texCoords0", the color attribute is called "a_color".
>   See ShaderProgram.POSITION_ATTRIBUTE, ShaderProgram.COLOR_ATTRIBUTE
>   and ShaderProgram.TEXCOORD_ATTRIBUTE which gets "0" appened to
>   indicate the use of the first texture unit. The projection matrix is
>   uploaded via a mat4 uniform called "u_proj", the transform matrix is
>   uploaded via a uniform called "u_trans", the combined transform and
>   projection matrx is is uploaded via a mat4 uniform called
>   "u_projTrans". The texture sampler is passed via a uniform called
>   "u_texture". Call this method with a null argument to use the default
>   shader.

Comment: Hmm, the GLSL spec contains: `In general, the language’s use of this character set is case sensitive.`. Does this mean Identifiers are case sensitive? The Identifiers section does not contain a word about it. (the vertex shader contains `a_Position`, the comment `a_position`)

Comment: Yep, looks like you were right.  I checked into how `SpriteBatch` creates its shader, and it was primarily a caps issue.  I also figured out what the default shaders are- I'll post those below.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After looking at the code in `SpriteBatch` it seems that I had a few mistakes in my code.  Below are the correct shaders:

**default.vert:**

```
attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec4 a_color;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord0;

uniform mat4 u_projTrans;

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoords;

void main() {
    v_color = a_color;
    v_texCoords = a_texCoord0;
    gl_Position = u_projTrans * a_position;
}
```

**default.frag:**

```
#ifdef GL_ES
    precision mediump float;
#endif

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoords;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = v_color * texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords);
}
```

Comment: Also the reason why this tutorial is broken:
https://github.com/mattdesl/lwjgl-basics/wiki/ShaderLesson1

Comment: This worked for me also in 2020. It seems there are a lot of wrong examples for this on the Internet and it is a bit frustrating with this multi dimensional API changes involving GL/GLSL/ES and libGDX version levels.